# Closed Covering of a Compact Space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I was having a little question on my mind for which I found no solution (by myself) even though it seems like something that I should be able to know.

What I was wondering is this:

For any compact space $K$, does there exist an infinite covering by closed sets from which we cannot extract a finite covering?

If so, can you please provide an example of such an infinite covering for a $k$-cell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oops... Can't believe I missed that... Please put it into an answer so I can accept your answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the space is infinite and $T_1$, just use the covering by singletons: $\big\{\{x\}:x\in X\big\}$.